# How to add <li> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to append `li` tag to existed `ul` tag using jQuery.

```
<li>
    <a data-action="action_name" href="#">Test</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Well, if you want to append it - do it. What is the problem?

Comment: Here [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: even the function has the same name as it is called, you definitly should read the docs first

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what selector you have for your ul element, you'd want to do something like

```
$('#id_of_your_ul').append(yourLiElement);
```

You can also select by class, or by tag, if there are no conflicts.

Quite an elementary task, you should try to refer to the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/) or a simple google search for terms such as "add element jquery".